# Does my Cuban girlfriend who has a student residence permit in Romania need a Transit Visa to travel to Cuba through Frankfurt?

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas, frankfurt, cuban-citizens

Hello and sorry if this has been asked a million times - I tried looking online and several websites seem to give conflicting answers.

So basically my girlfriend is from Cuba and she is a student here in Romania, so she has a temporary residence permit. She had a valid visa when she came here that was available for 90 days. After those 90 days she was required to check in with local authorities and get a temporary residence permit, so that's the only thing she has at hand.

She booked a flight to Varadero via Frankfurt, Germany, but we're not sure if she needs a transit visa to pass-through.

I found this document online:
https://www.germany.info/blob/917514/a968bd68b9f1e393da4f389dbba874c1/airport-transit-country-list-data.pdf
In there it is stated the people who ' hold a used valid or expired visa issued by Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland, Japan or Romania and return from the country of visa issuance and travel to a non-Schengen Member State.' do NOT require a transit visa, but I'm not sure if her residence permit OR her expired visa from when she arrived in Romania suffice.

Any information would be helpful.
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by temporary residence permit? How long is it valid? In general, residence permits are essentially equivalent to a visa for all this.

Comment: If 'temporary residence permit' means that your girl friend only has a document from the Romanian authorities confirming that she is allowed to stay in Romania while her application for a new residence permit is being processed, then it will not allow her to visit other Schengen countries. I'm not sure about the details in Romanian immigration law, but the permit may also just allow her to stay in Romania and not necessarily reenter if she leaves the country.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko Not correct - Germany requires an airport transit visa for Cubans. See https://www.germany.info/us-en/service/visa/airport-transit-visa/924624

Comment: @Johnnyjanko Unfortunately that changed at the end of July due to eg https://www.occrp.org/en/daily/17875-international-migrant-smuggling-ring-busted-62-arrested-in-5-country-operation

Comment: @Relaxed I meant it's not a permanent residence, just a 4 year residence until she finishes her studies, but it is valid until 2024. I think I got my answers so thank you all! :)

Comment: Thanks for the update, I'll remove my comment.